# Where can I get the complete English translation of the Chaitanya Bhagavata?

Tags: translation-request, chaitanya

Though Chaitanya Mahaprabhu's biography: Chaitanya Charitamrita is easily available on the web, I have been unavailable to find the complete English translation of the Chaitanya Bhagavata. Can you guys help me to find it?

Comment: Can I ask why you are so interested in Chaitanya?

Comment: Although I'm not a Gaudiya Vaishnava, Chaitanya is special to my heart because He's the one who brought me to Sanatana Dharma. It is Him who instilled bhakti into me. @Wikash_

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can read a complete English translation of Vrindavana Dasa Thakura's Chaitanya Bhagavata [here](https://archive.org/details/Chaitanya-Bhagavata_972).  Note that the Kandas are out of order; you should read th Adi Kanda, then the Madhya Kanda, then the Antya Kanda.

Answer (score 2):

You can download complete English translation of Chaitanya Bhagavata along with English translation of the commentary by BhaktiSiddhanta Sarasvati Thakur(originally written in Bengali).

[Adi Khanda](https://archive.org/details/CBAdi_201901)

[Madhya Khanda](https://archive.org/details/CBMadhya)

[Antya Khanda](https://archive.org/details/CBAntya)

Answer (score 2):

A translation by HG Kusakratha prabhu (ACBSP) can be found here: 
https://www.harekrsna.com/philosophy/gss/sastra/literature/texts/vrindaban.htm

A translation by HG Sarvabhavana prabhu (ACBSP) can be found here: 
https://archive.org/details/Chaitanya-Bhagavata_972

Translation of both text and commentary of Śrīla Bhaktisiddhānta Sarasvati by HG Bhumipati prabhu (ACBSP) can be found at https://archive.org/details/CBAdi_201901, https://archive.org/details/CBMadhya, https://archive.org/details/CBAntya

Comment: what does ACBSP mean?

Comment: They are all disciples of His Divine Grace A.C. Bhaktivedānta Swami Prabhupāda, Founder-ācārya of ISKCON...